# Return Bitmap image from function after decreasing quality

Tags: c#, bitmapimage

I go this function form internet. Which reduces the size of the image to 50%.
Now I am not able to return bitmap image form function below.

I am not able to find any method which current bitmap image to 50% and return it.

**Do I need to create a memory stream and then save it there?**

```
//reduce Image size
public void ReduceImageSize(Bitmap bmp1)
{
    var jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID 
    // for the Quality parameter category.
    var myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter 
    // objects. In this case, there is only one 
    // EncoderParameter object in the array.
    var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    //rather than saving it should set to the current bitmap image.
    //bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestPhoto\TestPhotoQualityFifty.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);


}
private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
{
    var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
    foreach (var codec in codecs)
    {
        if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
        {
            return codec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should save your file to memory only and then construct a new image from that memory:

```
using(var ram = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp1.Save(ram, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
    ram.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // reset stream to start so it can be read again
    return new Bitmap(ram);
}
```

Comment: Is there any kind of memory issue can come if we use this function if you call this function very frequent. Means may be an image per second with average size of 20 t 25 kb?

Comment: As the memory stream is `Dispose`d after each call, I don't see any issue with it. You still need to get rid of the old image though, right now you make two out of one source and keep both.